# Sub-matrices within a matrix

Tags: matrices

How can I draw the following type of matrix without changing the horizontal alignment of the column entries:

```
|   c11 c12 c13   c14   c15 c16   c17 | c18 c19 | |
|   c21 c22 c23   c24 | c25 c26 | c27   c28 c29   |
|   c31 c32 c33   c34 | c35 c36 | c37   c38 c39   |
| | c41 c42 c43 | c44   c45 c46   c47   c48 c49   |
```

Remark: There are three sub-matrices within the main matrix:

submatrix 1: c18 to c19
submatrix 2: c25 to c36
submatrix 3: c41 to c43

where `|` shows as the large-sized parentheses `(` and `)`.

This problem is different from 
[matrix in a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50627/matrix-in-a-matrix).

Answer (score 12):

## Remarks

I hope, I got your explanation right.

Using a specific `\tikzmark` and the `calligraphy` TikZ library by Andrew Stacey you can achieve the following output. You will need to rerun `latex` several times to get the positioning right.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calligraphy}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}}
\begin{document}
$
\begin{pmatrix}
    c11  & c12 & c13  & c14 & c15                   & c16                   & c17 & (c18 & c19) \\
    c12  & c22 & c23  & c24 & \tikzmark{c25}{$c25$} & \tikzmark{c26}{$c26$} & c27 & c28  & c29  \\
    c13  & c32 & c33  & c34 & \tikzmark{c35}{$c35$} & \tikzmark{c36}{$c36$} & c37 & c38  & c39  \\
    (c14 & c42 & c43) & c44 & c45                   & c46                   & c47 & c48  & c49  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={calligraphic straight parenthesis}] (c35.south west) -- (c25.north west);
    \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={calligraphic straight parenthesis}] (c26.north east) -- (c36.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

---

Using the `calc` library you can compensate the bad spacing for the TikZ braces by adding an offset of `.2em` as in

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={calligraphic straight parenthesis}] ($(c35.south west)+(-.2em,0)$) -- ($(c25.north west)+(-.2em,0)$);
    \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={calligraphic straight parenthesis}] ($(c26.north east)+(.2em,0)$) -- ($(c36.south east)+(.2em,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces

> [image]

---

On behalf of Christopher Creutzig's comment, here another solution (still using `tikzmark`) which doesn't involve typing parentheses inside the matrix.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations,calligraphy}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}}
\begin{document}
$
\begin{pmatrix}
    c11                   & c12 & c13                   & c14 & c15                   & c16                   & c17 & \tikzmark{c18}{$c18$} & \tikzmark{c19}{$c19$} \\
    c12                   & c22 & c23                   & c24 & \tikzmark{c25}{$c25$} & \tikzmark{c26}{$c26$} & c27 & c28                   & c29                   \\
    c13                   & c32 & c33                   & c34 & \tikzmark{c35}{$c35$} & \tikzmark{c36}{$c36$} & c37 & c38                   & c39                   \\
    \tikzmark{c14}{$c14$} & c42 & \tikzmark{c43}{$c43$} & c44 & c45                   & c46                   & c47 & c48                   & c49                   \\
\end{pmatrix}
$
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={calligraphic straight parenthesis}] ($(c35.south west)+(-.2em,0)$) -- ($(c25.north west)+(-.2em,0)$);
    \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={calligraphic straight parenthesis}] ($(c26.north east)+(.2em,0)$) -- ($(c36.south east)+(.2em,0)$);
    \node[left=.2em] at (c14) {$($};
    \node[left=.2em] at (c18) {$($};
    \node[right=.2em] at (c19) {$)$};
    \node[right=.2em] at (c43) {$)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: You have c14 and c18 shifted right and c43 and c19 shifted left. That probably calls for `\llap` and `\rlap`.

Answer (score 9):

The following MWE inserts the brackets (..) at the appropriate size:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(\begin{array}{@{\hspace*{1ex}}*{9}{c}@{\hspace*{1ex}}}
    c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} & c_{15} & c_{16} & c_{17} & \llap{$\bigl($}c_{18} & c_{19}\rlap{$\bigr)$} \\
    c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & c_{24} & \llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height}[0pt][0pt]{$\biggl($}}c_{25} & 
      c_{26}\rlap{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height}[0pt][0pt]{$\biggr)$}} & c_{27} & c_{28} & c_{29} \\
    c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33} & c_{34} & c_{35} & c_{36} & c_{37} & c_{38} & c_{39} \\
    \llap{$\bigl($}c_{41} & c_{42} & c_{43}\rlap{$\bigr)$} & c_{44} & c_{45} & c_{46} & c_{47} & c_{48} & c_{49}
  \end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Overlapping allows to maintain the horizontal spacing, while brackets are resized using their `\big`* equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` and its built-in command `\SubMatrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin]
c11 & c12 & c13 & c14 & c15 & c16 & c17 & c18 & c19 \\
c12 & c22 & c23 & c24 & c25 & c26 & c27 & c28 & c29 \\
c13 & c32 & c33 & c34 & c35 & c36 & c37 & c38 & c39 \\
c14 & c42 & c44 & c45 & c46 & c47 & c48 & c48 & c49 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix({1-7}{1-8})
  \SubMatrix({2-5}{3-6})
  \SubMatrix({4-1}{4-3})
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]