# \SubMatrix undefined in Overleaf

Tags: matrices, overleaf, undefined, nicematrix

I am interested in doing something similar to the situation outlined in [Sub-matrices within a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151464/sub-matrices-within-a-matrix/604585), but am unable to achieve the given output on Overleaf. Taking the following MWE from the linked question above

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin]
c11 & c12 & c13 & c14 & c15 & c16 & c17 & c18 & c19 \\
c12 & c22 & c23 & c24 & c25 & c26 & c27 & c28 & c29 \\
c13 & c32 & c33 & c34 & c35 & c36 & c37 & c38 & c39 \\
c14 & c42 & c44 & c45 & c46 & c47 & c48 & c48 & c49 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix({1-7}{1-8})
  \SubMatrix({2-5}{3-6})
  \SubMatrix({4-1}{4-3})
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

I **am** able to obtain the desired outcome when I compile locally, but not on Overleaf, which returns that `\SubMatrix` is an undefined control sequence.

How is it I should rectify this issue and successfully use the nicematrix package on Overleaf? The documentation for the package notes its use in Overleaf, so I'm sure that it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: It works perfectly now - my thanks!