# Text out of the row in table

Tags: tables

I want to center the text but it's keep getting out like this :
[image]

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{table}[]
\caption{Classification des canaux selon OSSTMM}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[HTML]{000000}}c|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &  &  & - Tester la sensibilisation du personnel à la   sécurité. \\ \cline{4-4} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &  & \multirow{-3}{*}{Humaine} & - Mesurer l’écart par rapport à la norme de sécurité requise dans la politique de sécurité de l’entreprise, les réglementations industrielles   ou la législation régionale.\\ \cline{3-4} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &\multirow{-3}{*}{\textbf{Sécurité physique}} & Physique & - Evaluer l’efficacité de systèmes de surveillance, des gardes et leurs emplacements dans l’installation, l’éclairage, le temps   de réaction.\\ \cline{2-4} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &  & Télécommunications & - Tous mode de communication vocale, à titre   d’exemple les PBX, la VOIP, etc. \\ \cline{3-4} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Sécurité des communications}} & Réseaux   des données & - Comprend tout système électronique et réseau de   données où l’interaction a lieu sur des lignes de réseau câblées et filaire. \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multirow{-17}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{OSSTMM}}} & \textbf{Sécurité   spectrale} & Communication sans fils & - Toute émission qui peut être interrompue ou   interceptée relève dans ce canal. \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to draw this one [image]

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Please provide a full compilable file beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's actually not a document it's my master's degree thesis, you are sure you want the whole code?

Comment: Not the whole code, rather a minimal working example  that generates the (first) table that you have created. It means you should add the document class, the required packages to create this table, and if you have defined any new commands.

Comment: I edited it and added the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `\multirowcell` command from the `makecell` package to insert a line break. Also, to rotate the content of the first column `\rotatebox` command from the `graphicx` package was used. And I removed all the `\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }` commands as they deemed unnecessary to me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{table}[htbp]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\caption{Classification des canaux selon OSSTMM}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[HTML]{000000}}c|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|m{7cm}|}
\hline
& \multirowcell{3}[-8ex][c]{\textbf{Sécurité}\\ \textbf{physique}} & \multirowcell{4.3}[0ex][c]{Humaine}  & - Tester la sensibilisation du personnel à la   sécurité. \\ \cline{4-4} 

& & & - Mesurer l’écart par rapport à la norme de sécurité requise dans la politique de sécurité de l’entreprise, les réglementations industrielles   ou la législation régionale.\\ \cline{3-4} 

& & Physique & - Evaluer l’efficacité de systèmes de surveillance, des gardes et leurs emplacements dans l’installation, l’éclairage, le temps   de réaction.\\ \cline{2-4} 
 
& \multirowcell{2}[-3ex][c]{\textbf{Sécurité des} \\\textbf{communications}}  & Télécommunications & - Tous mode de communication vocale, à titre   d’exemple les PBX, la VOIP, etc. \\ \cline{3-4} 

& & Réseaux   des données & - Comprend tout système électronique et réseau de   données où l’interaction a lieu sur des lignes de réseau câblées et filaire. \\ \cline{2-4} 

\multirowthead{-11.5}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{OSSTMM}}} & \textbf{Sécurité spectrale} & Communication sans fils & - Toute émission qui peut être interrompue ou   interceptée relève dans ce canal. \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Sadly, I don't know how to remove the ugly horizontal lines viewed in some viewers in the 1st column. Wish someone will provide a better solution.

Comment: Actually it does not show when I move from Latex to pdf , the problem is that I need it to  modify the width to fix some arrow where the woods keep getting out, I don't know if this is because I am using overleaf?

Comment: AFAIK, this difference in the colored column in different viewers doesn't occur if `nicematrix` package is used. I haven't yet get acquainted with that package, so couldn't provide a solution using that package.

Comment: @DidyouknowTHAT Sorry can't understand the 2nd part of your comment. I have also used Overleaf.

Comment: @Imran for the ugly horizontal lines  -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610124/197451  and this for overleaf compatibility -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611901/197451

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You won't see thin white lines in the black panel, whatever PDF viewer you use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\caption{Classification des canaux selon OSSTMM}
\label{tab:my-table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccm[c]{3.1cm}X[m]}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\Block[fill=black]{*-1}{\rotate\sffamily\color{white} OSSTMM}
& 
\Block{2-1}{Sécurité physique} & 
Humaine & 
--\kern1mm Tester la sensibilisation du personnel à la sécurité. \newline
--\kern1mm Mesurer l’écart par rapport à la norme de sécurité requise dans
 la politique de sécurité de l’entreprise, les réglementations industrielles 
ou la législation régionale. \\
& 
& 
Physique &
--\kern1mm Évaluer l’efficacité de systèmes de surveillance, des gardes et 
leurs emplacements dans l’installation, l’éclairage, le temps de réaction. \\
& 
\Block{2-1}{Sécurité des\\ communications} &   
Télécommunications & 
--\kern1mm Tous mode de communication vocale, à titre d’exemple les PBX, la VOIP, etc. \\
& 
& 
Réseaux des données & 
--\kern1mm Comprend tout système électronique et réseau de données où l’interaction 
a lieu sur des lignes de réseau câblées et filaire. \\
& 
\Block{}{Sécurité spectrale} & 
Communication sans fils & 
--\kern1mm Toute émission qui peut être interrompue ou interceptée relève dans ce canal. \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]