# Align matrices in Texmaker

Tags: matrices

I'm new to LaTeX and I wanna know how to make exactly this with LaTeX code.

[image]

I tried to use `eqnarray` to get the numbers but I get errors. Also, I tried to align the last 3 matrices but they all get centered and get appeared in a row one after another.

My code:

```
\[
\textbf{I=}\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\[
\textbf{I=}\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\[
\textbf{I=}\begin{Bmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{Bmatrix}
\]

\[
\textbf{I=}\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{vmatrix}
\]

\[
\textbf{I=}\begin{Vmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{Vmatrix}
\]
```

Comment: Could you post your code, not a screenshot?

Comment: \[
\textbf{I=}\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\[
\textbf{I=}\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\[
\textbf{I=}\begin{Bmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{Bmatrix}
\]

\[
\textbf{I=}\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{vmatrix}
\]

\[
\textbf{I=}\begin{Vmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{Vmatrix}
\]

Comment: Please update your post with this code.

Comment: Did it. Sorry for the way it appears :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should never have multiple display math environments (like `\[ ... \]` or `\begin{equation} .. \end{equation}`) after each other. The `amsmath` package provides several environments for multi-line displayed math. In this case, you want the `gather` environment I think.

After the first and the second matrix I added a linebreak with `\\`. After the third and the fourth, I added some horizontal space with `\qquad`.

Note also that you should have `\mathbf{I}=..`, not `\textbf{I=}`. With the latter you get the wrong spacing around the `=`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\mathbf{I}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\mathbf{I}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\mathbf{I}=\begin{Bmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{Bmatrix},
\qquad
\mathbf{I}=\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{vmatrix},
\qquad
\mathbf{I}=\begin{Vmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{Vmatrix}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Another possibility might be using `align` instead of `gather`, and add a `&` before selected `=`, to align those horizontally.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{I}&=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\mathbf{I}&=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\mathbf{I}=\begin{Bmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{Bmatrix},
\qquad
\mathbf{I}&=\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{vmatrix},
\qquad
\mathbf{I}=\begin{Vmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{Vmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two codes to do that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{2pt}

\begin{document}


\[ \makegapedcells \begin{matrix*}[l]   
  & \mathbf{I=}\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\\
  &  \mathbf{I=}\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}\\
  \mathbf{I=}\begin{Bmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{Bmatrix},
  & \mathbf{I=}\:\begin{vmatrix}\, 1&0&0&0\, \\\, 0&1&0&0 \,\\\, 0&0&1&0\,\\ \,0&0&0&1 \,\end{vmatrix},
  &  \mathbf{I=}\begin{Vmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{Vmatrix}
  \end{matrix*} \]


  \begin{alignat}{3}
      &   & \mathbf{I=}& \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\\
      &   & \mathbf{I=}& \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}\\
    & \mathbf{I=}\begin{Bmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{Bmatrix},
    &\quad  \mathbf{I=}& \:\begin{vmatrix}\, 1&0&0&0\, \\\, 0&1&0&0 \,\\\, 0&0&1&0\,\\ \,0&0&0&1 \,\end{vmatrix},
    & \quad \mathbf{I=}& \begin{Vmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{Vmatrix}
  \end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that the original image displays equation numbers on the right.

Comment: I hadn't notice. In such a case you need the second solution, just unstarring `alignat*`. Please see my updated answer if it's OK.

Comment: what's the purpose of including the `=` within the `\mathbf` scope?  it has no effect.

Comment: It was so in the OP. Don't know if there was a serious reason for this.

Comment: There are a few commas missing in the solution.

Comment: @Budo Zindovic: I know, but I removed them for consistency. The first two rows have no comma. Anyway, it's easy to add them.

Comment: @Bernard: No problem, I was merely referring to the images posted by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Every matrix should be an element of a super-matrix. See the answer in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50627/matrix-in-a-matrix).

You can also do it like this. Put `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble and then put this in you document:

```
\begin{align}
&& FIRST MATRIX && \\
&& SECOND MATRIX && \\
THIRD MATRIX, && FOURTH MATRIX, && FIFTH MATRIX
\end{align}
```

Every row will have equation number on the right.

You can just fill the placeholders with your own matrices.

Comment: Which means what exactly?

Comment: I've added an example from tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Still dont get it

Comment: In the {} i dont write anything right? In FIRST MATRIX, SECOND MATRIX etc position i onsert only the numbers with the &?

Comment: You just write your first matrix instead of FIRST MATRIX, etc. Instead of FIRST MATRIX, you should put `\textbf{I=}\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}`