# Brackets inside brackets with newline inside

Tags: matrices, arrays, brackets

My question is how to achieve this effect in LaTeX? I tried various combinations of `\right` and `\left` but it does not work.

[image]

**EDIT**

Adding the code:

```
    $[introduces]m$ = $\left[ 
    o_1 = \left\lbrack[o_1 
    \newline
    o_2
    o_3] \right\rbrack
    o_2 = \lbrack \rbrack
    \right]$
```

Comment: You may consider this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50627/matrix-in-a-matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `array` nested in `array`, but in this case I believe `aligned` is better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left[
\begin{aligned}
o_1 & \mapsto
  \left[
  \begin{aligned}
  o_1 & \mapsto 1 \\
  o_2 & \mapsto 0 \\
  o_3 & \mapsto 0
  \end{aligned}
  \right]
\\
o_2 & \mapsto
  \left[
  \begin{aligned}
  o_1 & \mapsto 1 \\
  o_2 & \mapsto 1 \\
  o_3 & \mapsto 0
  \end{aligned}
  \right]
\\
o_3 & \mapsto
  \left[
  \begin{aligned}
  o_1 & \mapsto 0 \\
  o_2 & \mapsto 0 \\
  o_3 & \mapsto 1
  \end{aligned}
  \right]
\end{aligned}
\right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without overshooting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{aligned}
o_1 & \mapsto
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{aligned}
  o_1 & \mapsto 1 \\
  o_2 & \mapsto 0 \\
  o_3 & \mapsto 0
  \end{aligned}
  \end{bmatrix}
\\
o_2 & \mapsto
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{aligned}
  o_1 & \mapsto 1 \\
  o_2 & \mapsto 1 \\
  o_3 & \mapsto 0
  \end{aligned}
  \end{bmatrix}
\\
o_3 & \mapsto
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{aligned}
  o_1 & \mapsto 0 \\
  o_2 & \mapsto 0 \\
  o_3 & \mapsto 1
  \end{aligned}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The smaller brackets overshoot a bit at the top and the bottom. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @marmot It's just the default output. I don't think it's bad.

Comment: But how to move it to left side? Like \noindent does it?

Comment: @KompiKompi I don't think you want such a big object not to be displayed.

Comment: *I* don’t like the overshoot of the inner brackets: may I respectfully suggest adding `\noalign{\smallskip}` at the top and bottom of the outer `aligned`? :-)

Comment: @GuM You can suggest. `;-)` I can do it differently. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{bmatrix}
    \addlinespace
    \;o_1 & \longmapsto \begin{bmatrix}
      o_1 & \longmapsto 1 \\
      o_2 & \longmapsto 0 \\
      o_3 & \longmapsto 0
    \end{bmatrix}\;
    \\
    \addlinespace
    \;o_2 & \longmapsto \begin{bmatrix}
      o_1 & \longmapsto 1 \\
      o_2 & \longmapsto 1 \\
      o_3 & \longmapsto 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\;\\
    \addlinespace
    \;o_3 & \longmapsto \begin{bmatrix}
      o_1 & \longmapsto 0 \\
      o_2 & \longmapsto 0 \\
      o_3 & \longmapsto 1
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    \addlinespace
  \end{bmatrix}\; \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there an extra `\;` after the first inner bmatrix?

Comment: Yes, I added some padding between the inner matrices and the outer one, for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: but shouldn't it be also then with the second and third? as it stands alignment is weird

Comment: You're right. I guess I tgought of it as `<{\;}` in the preamble of an array. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are more compact vertically and seem nice for this job. Adding `@{~\mapsto~}` to the column specification also saves some typing and makes the code cleaner.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c @{~~\mapsto~~} c}
      o_1 & \left[\begin{array}{c @{~\mapsto~} c}
      o_1 & 1 \\
      o_2 & 0 \\
      o_3 & 0
    \end{array} \right] \\ [1.5em]
      o_2 & \left[\begin{array}{c @{~\mapsto~} c}
      o_1 & 1 \\
      o_2 & 1 \\
      o_3 & 0 \\
    \end{array} \right]\\ [1.5em]
      o_3 & \left[\begin{array}{c @{~\mapsto~} c}
      o_1 & 0 \\
      o_2 & 0 \\
      o_3 & 1
    \end{array} \right] \\   
    \end{array} 
  \right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]